How to prevent duplicate activations of menu items in "_blank" tabs?
I am using a vertical side-navigation menu with drop-down buttons. Since I prefer users to be able to work on several menu/sub-menu options simultaneously, I set up each button press to generate a corresponding screen in its own tab by using target="_blank"... Furthermore, for the sake of uniformity and efficiency, I'd like to avoid having to go back to Home screen for each additional menu option activation, which is why I plan to repeat displaying the same Home screen menu in the code for each of the launched tabs. My problem: I also want to prevent re-launching menu/sub-menu functions that have already been activated in their own tabs. While showing the menu in its original form, this would probably require disabling the menu/sub-menu items that have already been activated.
Being new at this skill, I have no clue how to build this capability into the  code (see attached). Clearly, I need help and hope I'm not asking for too much.
Thank you,
Eitan
Below are my current html and JS code blocks:
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Intake (3)
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="send.html"     target="_blank">Send</a>
      <a href="uploaded.html" target="_blank" >Uploaded</a>
      <a href="others.html"   target="_blank">Others</a>
  </div>

  <a href="pending.html" target="_blank">Pending</a> 
  <a href="filed.html"   target="_blank">Filed</a>
  <a href="view.html"    target="_blank">View</a>
  <a href="search.html"  target="_blank">Search</a>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">WorkFlow (2)
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="wf-task1.html" target="_blank">WF-task1</a>
      <a href="wf-task2.html" target="_blank">WF-task2</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">Admin (3) 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="admin1.html" target="_blank">Admin1</a>
      <a href="admin2.html" target="_blank">Admin2</a>
      <a href="admin3.html" target="_blank">Admin3</a>
  </div> 

  
  

      var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
      var i;
  
      for (i = 0; i 

Your question is how to hide URLs when the user already opened them ?

I think you're correct. But how do I do it?

The easy solution would be getting the active tabs, but no browser can provide that functionality for privacy reason so i think you should look into BroadcastChannel and implement your own logic

If the new "_blank" tab was opened by your page, you can keep track of it. Then, when the user clicks again on the link in your Home page, check if the tab was closed or not. It it was closed, discard; if it is not closed, open. For this, though, you would have to intercept the click on the link.
Basically, you HTML would look like this:
<a href="send.html"     target="_blank" onclick="checkIfOpened(this)">Send</a>
<a href="uploaded.html" target="_blank" onclick="checkIfOpened(this)" >Uploaded</a>
<a href="others.html"   target="_blank" onclick="checkIfOpened(this)">Others</a>

In javascript, you do:
var opened_tabs = [];
function checkIfOpened(elem) {
    window.event.preventDefault();
    if (opened_tabs[elem.href] && !opened_tabs[elem.href].closed) {
        alert('Tab already opened.');
    } else {
        opened_tabs[elem.href] = window.open(elem.href,"_blank");
    }
}

